# Why it is necessary to restart every service in jitsi if some changes made to prosody?

Tags: docker, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I'm using docker setup and whenever I made any changes to `prosody` then I have to remove the previous config of `jicofo` and `jvb` and then need to **restart** both the services. If I don't restart then `jicofo` started showing error like `unable to connect to xmpp.meet.jitsi`. Is is possible to fix this? Please help.